# Codeigniter path to specific folder in a model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to locate to a specific folder in my project from a model
It works great on my local environment but when I deploy the app it doesnt work :'(

this is the models path:

> projectname/application/modules/site/models/model.php

this is the folders path

> projectname/www/client/myfolder

now how I got the path locally is like this:

```
FCPATH."myfolder/
```

When I deploy it, it doesnt work and dumps a very large url
(probably because it's starting from the servers root or something?

```
/data/sites/web/hostingname/subsites/staging/www/client/myfolder
```

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

I know there is APPPATH but I dont need the application folder I need the www folder that is on the same level as the application folder

If anyone can help me out that woudl be realy cool :)

Many thanks in advance!

### EDIT

If I do this i get an empty array:

```
    public function getSlidesForPresentation($presentation)
    {
        $directory = base_url('/myfolder') ."/". $var."/slides/";
    
        $filepaths = glob($directory . "*");
    
        $slides = array();
    
        foreach($filepaths as $filepath) {
            $slide = substr($filepath, strpos($filepath, "/client/") + 8);
    
            $slides[] = $slide;
        }
    
        return $slides;
    }


If i do this everyhting works great

public function getSlidesForPresentation($presentation)
    {
        $directory = FCPATH."myfolder/".$var."/slides/";

        $filepaths = glob($directory . "*");

        $slides = array();

        foreach($filepaths as $filepath) {
            $slide = substr($filepath, strpos($filepath, "/client/") + 8);

            $slides[] = $slide;
        }

        return $slides;
    }
```

What in the world is going on??

I did a var_dump($filepaths) and i get this:
/data/sites/web/hostname/subsites/staging/www/client/myfolder/1/slides/01.jpg

this is the filepath of the image:
hostname/subsites/staging/www/client/myfolder/1/slides/01.jpg

So I don't understand why the image isnt found :'(

Comment: are you looking for `getcwd() `

Comment: @Saty I tried this out and gives me same result as FCPATH

Comment: FCPATH is the way to go. Is there an actual error in either output or logs?

Comment: @qwertzman no error and nothing in the logs, it just doesn't find the files since that function returns an empty array

Comment: If you mean the function with base_url() it will not work. in the one with FCPATH try to print $directory, check if it exists, var_dump($filepaths) and see if it doesnt return false.

Comment: It comes down to debugging at this point. Print out $filepath inside the foreach and use die; die make breakpoints. Or var_dump($slides);die; after the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul try with the URl Helper from CI.

Try with `base_url('www/client/myfolder')`

You need to declare your site base url in config.php to use this function.

EDIT:

```
 public function getSlidesForPresentation($presentation)
    {
    $directory = base_url('/myfolder/'.$var.'/slides');

    $slides = array();

    $handle = opendir($directory);

    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    $slide = substr($entry, strpos($entry, "/client/") + 8);

    $slides[] = $slide;
    }
    return $slides;
}
}
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: you method works but the rest of my function doesnt work anymore can you check it out? i edited OP

Comment: can you post the result of var_dump(base_url('/myfolder') ."/". $var."/slides/")?
I think you added an extra slash inside base_url().

Comment: no that is not the case I think the problem is that my function is setup to loop over a directory (a filepath) and not an url

Comment: I don't think base_url is the way to go either since i need a filepath and not an url